# Unable to validate jQuery multiselect dropdown with id

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery multi-select drop down box. Because of it's default property I am unable to validate it with it's name attribute. So that I would like to validate with id. I am using [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-validating-on-input-id-instead-of-name#14737000002034857) as reference. But my idea is not working. I don't know where my mistake is??

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <select name="offer" id="offer1">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="aaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
        <option value="bbbbb">bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
        <option value="cccccc">ccccccccccc</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" value="Save" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit1").click(function () {
        alert("submit")
        var $off = $("#offer1").attr("name");
        var $params = {
            debug: true,
            rules: {},
            messages: {}
        };
        $params['rules'][$off] = "off";
        $params['messages'][$off] = "Select an offer";

        $("#form1").validate($params);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgDDz/)

Comment: your select-tag is closing wrong

Comment: After that also my validation is not working

Comment: What isn't working, are there any errors? Your fiddle doesn't have jquery or jquery validation plugin. Are you linking to them before you try and validate?

Comment: @gwillie-sorry. corrected my fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the [ ] in adding rule and message

The answer  is:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit1").click(function () {
        alert("submit");
        var $off = $("#offer1").attr("name");
        var $params = {
            debug: true,
            rules: {},
            messages: {}
        };

       //// Please note here
          $params.rules [$off] = "required";    
           $params.messages[$off] = "Select an offer";

      //
        $("#form1").validate($params);
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't add multiple ans. You can edit your first ans if you want to do some  change.

Comment: -1, You absolutely do not need to put `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` call is the **one-time** _initialization_ method and therefore does not need to be repeatedly called on button `click`.  The click event of the submit button is automatically captured by the plugin.  I know you're just copying the OP's code, however, if you're going to post an answer, it might as well promote the proper usage.  @Sam, see:  http://jsfiddle.net/BzSLC/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**HTML CODE**

```
<form id="RNA" name="RNA">
  <select size="5" name="sampleMut[]" multiple="multiple" id="sampleMut">
   <option value="41" >41</option>
   <option value="48" >48</option>
   <option value="65" >65</option>
   <option value="102" >102</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript CODE**

```
$(function(){
$('form').submit(function(){
     var options = $('#sampleMut > option:selected');
     if(options.length == 0){
         alert('no value selected');
         return false;
     }
 });
});
```

You can select multiple value from this select. `options.length` gives you how many values you select.

Answer (score 0):

enclose `<option>` tags *inside* your `<select>` tag

```
<select name="offer" id="offer1>
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="aaaaa">aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option value="bbbbb">bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
    <option value="cccccc">ccccccccccc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this:

```
$(function () {

 $("#submit1").click(function(){
 alert("submit");
 $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            offer: "required"

        },
        messages: {
            offer: "Select an Offer"

        }
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: -1, You absolutely do not need to put `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` call is the **one-time** _initialization_ method and therefore does not need to be repeatedly called on button `click`.  The click event of the submit button is automatically captured by the plugin.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/BzSLC/